# Could 'being' use as a main verb?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I read a following sentence in the book **Data structure and algorithm in Python**:

> A tour instance is created by sending a reference to a specific tree to the constructor, and then by calling the public 'executed' method, which **beings** the tour and returns a final result of the computation.

I am confused about the use of **being**. As I known, **being** can use in a present or past continuous tense as following:

- He is being nice.
- She was being bad.

But I don't know whether **being** can be used as a main verb like that. If can, does its meaning is same as it used in the present  continuous tense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think maybe it should be **begins**, it's a typo, since the *tour* is a datastructure transversal starting with a call to a method.

Answer (score 5):

You are right to be confused!  The word is definitely a typo.  Without more context, it is impossible to know what word was intended, but from the small amount of text I can see here, "begins" is a pretty reasonable guess.

Comment: http://multimedia.ucc.ie/Public/training/cycle1/algorithms-in-python.pdf - page 342. "Begins" is probably correct.